# Flex 4 mx:HDividedBox flicker with liveDragging enabled *only* when mouse is over component

Tags: apache-flex, mouseover, drag, flicker

I've noticed that an "out of the box" HDividedBox has some serious flickering issues when liveDragging is enabled, ***but only when the pointer is over the contents of the DividedBox while dragging***.  If you grab the BoxDivider and move the pointer off the component while dragging, the flicker goes away and the component renders properly.

I have tested this with both my customized component and an extremely basic HDividedBox implementation with Group, SkinnableContainer, and BoxContainer children as well as nested groups with clipping.  All types of children exhibit the same behavior.  If someone has a workaround for this I would greatly appreciate some input!!

Thanks a lot, and here's a code snippet that shows my issue.

```
 <mx:HDividedBox width="500" height="200" liveDragging="true">
      <s:SkinnableContainer minWidth="0" backgroundColor="green" percentHeight="100"/>
      <s:SkinnableContainer minWidth="0" backgroundColor="blue" percentHeight="100"/>
      <s:SkinnableContainer minWidth="0" backgroundColor="yellow" percentHeight="100"/>
      <s:SkinnableContainer minWidth="0" backgroundColor="red" percentHeight="100"/>
 </mx:HDividedBox>
```

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

As fun as it was to pull the dividers around and see how that sample behaves, I did not experience any flickering issues.  Possible explanations:

1. Processor speed - I run a fast processor, some others may not be able to keep up with the required number of redraws. You may also be working with more complex components that are more difficult to draw than solid colors.
2. Mouse events may be getting dispatched/handled multiple times in the components you are using.
3. I did experience some divider 'twitching' when moving the bars occasionally.  The is most likely due to the multiple layout computations necessary to compute the correct widths of each divided box based on percentages, every time a divider moves just a pixel.

Edit: Run this and move the dividers to get an idea of how many resizes/redraws are occurring due to using livedragging:.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:int id = "resizeCount">0</fx:int>
</fx:Declarations>


    <mx:HDividedBox 
        width = "500" height = "200"
        liveDragging = "true">
        <s:SkinnableContainer 
            minWidth = "0"
            percentHeight = "100"
            backgroundColor = "green"

            resize = "{trace(resizeCount);resizeCount++}" />
        <s:SkinnableContainer 
            minWidth = "0"
            percentHeight = "100"
            backgroundColor = "blue"

            resize = "{trace(resizeCount);resizeCount++}" />
        <s:SkinnableContainer 
            minWidth = "0"
            percentHeight = "100"
            backgroundColor = "yellow"

            resize = "{trace(resizeCount);resizeCount++}" />
        <s:SkinnableContainer 
            minWidth = "0"
            percentHeight = "100"
            backgroundColor = "red"

            resize = "{trace(resizeCount);resizeCount++}" />
    </mx:HDividedBox>
```

It quickly gets into the hundreds... then thousands...

Comment: Hmm... I'm running a very fast processor as well.  I've been able to reproduce this using the code I posted on 4 different boxes now.  It usually requires fast dragging, and it will appear on the right edge of the element directly to the right of the divider.

Comment: What browser, OS, and flash version are you using?  I tried both Chrome with whatever the latest version of flash is that it auto-uses and IE9 with a relatively recent version of the debugger flash plugin.  This was on Windows 7 with a i7 920 @3.8ghz...

Comment: I am on an iMac running OSX 10.6.6 with an i3 3.06GHz & 4GB of RAM...  Flash 10.1.102.64.  You definitely have more horsepower than I, so that could explain why you aren't seeing it, I guess.  I tried in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all with the same results on both my iMAc and an XP Core2 Duo 3Ghz box with 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Ah, Flash is known to run worse on OSX than Windows.  I've never experienced it as I'm a Windows guy, but I've definitely seen it reported many times, such as here: http://superuser.com/questions/91318/poor-flash-performance-on-mac-os-x  If you have a windows machine in the house, give it a try on that and share the results.

Comment: I have checked on a Windows XP Core2 Duo 3Ghz box with 4 GB RAM with all of the same browsers with the same results.  I can see poor Flash performance being a culprit if this were dealing with processor intensive calculations like 3D rendering, but we're talking about rendering a single sprite here... shouldn't be a processing hog, right?

Comment: Edited my answer to show what is really happening - it isn't just a redraw of a single sprite when a divider moves.

Comment: Adding trace logging creates a noticeable difference in the flickering, so that tells me it is probably a processing power issue...  I know it's re-drawing it many many times, but I still can't figure out how Flash can do impressive 2D and 3D gaming stories, but can't handle a fluid resize of a divider...  Thanks for your input - I guess I'm going to bail on the liveDragging.  That's disappointing!

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but this still doesn't explain why when dragging without the cursor over the component the flickering goes away.  To me, all signs are pointing to unexpected/unnecessary event dispatching.